# Bringing a lightsaber / staff through Singapore airport from Germany

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, singapore

I have bough this [Starwars Rey staff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U6429DG) and I'm flying from Germany (Frankfurt) to Singapore. Would it be a problem when I check in the item in my luggage at Frankfurt airport?

Singapore have some strict rules on prohibited items too (http://www.customs.gov.sg/individuals/going-through-customs/arrival/prohibited-and-controlled-goods). Would my staff be allowed through the customs at the airport?

What about lightsabers? Would something like this (http://www.ultraforcesabers.com/hasbro/force_fx_lightsabers/Vader_ANH_Black_Series) gets pass the Singapore and Germany customs?

Comment: I don't quite see which item on the prohibited or controlled goods list the staff may enter into. Given that it's plastic and made of 3 pieces, I doubt it could really be considered a weapon. Note that toy versions of guns, pistols and revolvers need authorisation, but they say nothing about toy versions of other weapons.

Comment: I'm relocating to Singapore and i've half a suitcase load of legos too, I'm not sure whether I've to pay taxes for those (they're for my personal collection, not for sale).

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I'm curious as to why Amazon put that staff in the "*men's* costume accessories" section. Clearly they haven't seen the film...

Comment: @user568458 note that Amazon categorization is absolutely unreliable. For eg https://twitter.com/chx/status/659908490853355521 and https://twitter.com/chx/status/616175554157371392 https://twitter.com/chx/status/616155090710212609 are just a few I stumbled upon over the last year.

Comment: Just tell them it's part of your Jedi religion.

Comment: By the way, if you are reading @TheMathemagician comment, [Jedism **is** a religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jediism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **highly unlikely** that you will encounter difficulty with travelling from Germany to Singapore with this.

I don't contemplate any reasonable reading of the prohibited or controlled goods import lists that would preclude you from carrying your lightsaber.

I also don't see any reasonable reading of [German regulations](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Leaving-Germany/Restrictions/restrictions_node.html) that would prevent you from checking in your lightsaber.

Comment: I got through from Frankfurt to Singapore with my Rey staff and my legos!!!